# When showing two modal at a time with react-bootstrap in reactjs, how to show gray area above the first modal and below the second modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I am showing two modal at a time in my react application. Currently it's working fine and looks like this.

[image]

But the keyboard modal is not focused properly because the gray area is below all two modals. I want to show the gray area above the big modal when the small modal is active.
How can I achieve this?
I'm using react-bootstrap to show modals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The z-index property in CSS controls the vertical stacking order of elements that overlap.
Elements with a higher z-index value are displayed in front of those with a lower z-index value.
So apply more z-index to component which you want on Top in your case Keyboard Component.

```
 <BigModal style={{ position: 'relative', zIndex: '1' }} />

 <GrayArea style={{ position: 'relative', zIndex: '2' }} />

 <TopModal style={{ position: 'relative', zIndex: '3' }} />
```